# How to type-hint an Enum of strings in Python

Tags: python, types, enums, mypy

I was curious how I'd type-hint an enumeration of strings, for example:
["keyword1", "keyword2"]

I'd want some variable, v, to be equal to any of these string literals. I could accomplish this with a union of literals - Union[Literal["keyword1"], Literal["keyword2"]] but it'd be make maintainability difficult if one of these keywords gets changed in the future.
Ideally, I'd want to define things like this:

```
class Keywords(enum):
   keywordOne = "keyword1"
   keywordTwo = "keyword2"
v: valueOf[Keywords] = Keywords.keywordOne.value # v = "keyword1"
```

But I'm not sure how to accomplish something like this in MyPy

Answer (score 5):

You're nearly there. It seems like what you're looking for is a custom enum object that is itself typed and then type annotations that dictate the use of that enum. Something like this:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Literal

class CustomKeyword(Enum):
   keywordOne: Literal["keyword1"] = "keyword1"
   keywordTwo: Literal["keyword2"] = "keyword2"

v: CustomKeyword = CustomKeyword.keywordOne
```

Does this not give you the expected outcome?

Comment: This doesn't type-check unfortunately. keywordOne: Literal["keyword1"] = "keyword1", for example, doesn't work because we're assigning keywordOne an enum value not a literal. (This is an issue with Python)

Comment: I must be confused about what you're saying because this type checks for me using mypy. If I change keywordOne's value either in the initial assignment or later I will get mypy errors: 

test.py:5: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Literal['foo']", variable has type "Literal['keyword1']")
test.py:10: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Literal['bar']", variable has type "Literal['keyword1']")
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Comment: That's so odd. Your code verbatim doesn't type-check on my machine, it must be something on my end then

Comment: Just so we're on the same page -- you know that mypy is a standalone type checker that runs independent of code execution? Type checking isn't built-in and you'll need to run "mypy test.py" or similar to get the output above.

Comment: Yep, we are! That code executes fine, it's specifically flagged by pyright in VSCode, but mypy itself doesn't seem to care. I'm gonna just chalk this up to my local configuration being wrong somewhere